# How can I get interline spacing to ignore a vbox?

Tags: line-spacing, plain-tex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make an invisible vbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22355/make-an-invisible-vbox)

I want to insert a `\vbox` between paragraphs, but I do not want it to affect interline spacing. I'm using Plain TeX. Here is my MWE:

```
\input plain
asdljflasd dasjfdlf lasdfdflaslfjlsadf sajf lsdfas Lorem ipsum dolor
sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sollicitudin pretium\par
\nointerlineskip\vbox to 0pt{\hbox to 0pt{\hskip -10pt *}\kern0pt}\nointerlineskip
In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Etiam rutrum blandit velit sed
rutrum. Curabitur rhoncus erat a turpis suscipit vitae rutrum turpis

\bye
```

The below shows bad spacing between the two paragraphs (where the asterisk appears):

[image: Bad Spacing]

Commenting out the line beginning with `\nointerlineskip` gives correct spacing between the two paragraphs:

[image: Good spacing]

How do I get my `\vbox` and correct interline spacing? Apologies for the huge images.

Comment: Found my answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22355/make-an-invisible-vbox. Thanks related sidebar!

Comment: _Please_ use a minimal page size in future images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has to work a bit harder to get everything in the correct place:

```
asdljflasd dasjfdlf lasdfdflaslfjlsadf sajf lsdfas Lorem ipsum dolor
sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sollicitudin pretium

\edef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}\nointerlineskip
\vbox to 0pt{\hrule height 0pt\prevdepth=\tpd\llap{\strut*\kern10pt}\vss}%
\prevdepth=\tpd
In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Etiam rutrum blandit velit sed
rutrum. Curabitur rhoncus erat a turpis suscipit vitae rutrum turpis
```

However, putting an asterisk in the margin is much easier than that:

```
\def\marginasterisk{\leavevmode\llap{*\kern\parindent\kern10pt}}

asdljflasd dasjfdlf lasdfdflaslfjlsadf sajf lsdfas Lorem ipsum dolor
sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sollicitudin pretium

\marginasterisk In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Etiam rutrum blandit velit sed
rutrum. Curabitur rhoncus erat a turpis suscipit vitae rutrum turpis
```

Comment: Why is all the necessary in the \vbox? Especially the \hrule and \vss?

Comment: @JustinBailey The `\hrule` puts the reference point exactly at the uppermost level of the `\vbox` that will thus have zero height. The `\vss` is to avoid an underfull vbox. With `\prevdepth=\tpd` I ensure that the correct interline glue is inserted before the box with the asterisk and also between paragraphs.

Answer (score 2):

Alterative may be to use `\vtop` instead of `\vbox` and omit `\nointerlineskip` before:

```
asdljflasd dasjfdlf lasdfdflaslfjlsadf sajf lsdfas Lorem ipsum dolor
sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sollicitudin pretium\par
\vtop to 0pt{\hbox to 0pt{\hskip -10pt *}\kern 0pt}%
\nointerlineskip
In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Etiam rutrum blandit velit sed
rutrum. Curabitur rhoncus erat a turpis suscipit vitae rutrum turpis

\bye
```