# \vbox with some extra space below

Tags: tex-core, boxes, line-spacing, grid-typesetting

I don't understand why when using `\vbox` of a certain height, there is some extra space added below it.

I'm trying - towards grid typesetting - to put for example graphics in the vbox of a certain height (say `2 \baselineskip`), so the picture should occupy the multiplicity of `\baselineskip`. However, it fails, since some extra space is added below the `\vbox`. Why?

I've tried to use `\nointerlineskip` after the `\vbox`, but no result.

I'm aware of the post [How can I get interline spacing to ignore a vbox?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37321/how-can-i-get-interline-spacing-to-ignore-a-vbox) , but it does not help me.

There is a MWE below, I include some rulers to more easily clarify the problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}  
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%% rulers
\usepackage{atbegshi,picture}
\makeatletter 
\AtBeginShipout{%
\AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
  \put(\dimexpr
    \ifodd\value{page}\oddsidemargin\else\evensidemargin\fi + 1in\relax,
      -\dimexpr\topmargin + 1in + \headheight + \headsep\relax){%
       \begin{picture}(0,0)%
       \setlength{\unitlength}{13bp}%
        \setlength{\dimen0 }{0pt}%
        \@whiledim\dimen0<\dimexpr\textheight+1sp\relax\do{%
        \put(0,-\dimen0){\line(1,0){\textwidth}}%
        \addtolength{\dimen0 }{\unitlength}%
      }%
   \end{picture}%
  }%
 }%
}
\makeatother
 \makeatletter
 \setlength{\topskip}{13bp}
 \renewcommand\normalsize{%
  % \baselineskip to 13bp for \normalsize
  \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xipt{13bp}%
  % the following values are taken from size11.clo.
  \abovedisplayskip 11\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus6\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6.5\p@ \@plus3.5\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI 
   }
   \usepackage{parskip}
   \setlength{\parskip}{13bp}
   \makeatother
  \begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
  \vbox to 2\baselineskip{ }
   \lipsum[1]
   \end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

You need to take care of the depth of the previous line.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}  
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%% rulers
\usepackage{atbegshi,picture}
\makeatletter 
\AtBeginShipout{%
\AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
  \put(\dimexpr
    \ifodd\value{page}\oddsidemargin\else\evensidemargin\fi + 1in\relax,
      -\dimexpr\topmargin + 1in + \headheight + \headsep\relax){%
       \begin{picture}(0,0)%
       \setlength{\unitlength}{13bp}%
        \setlength{\dimen0 }{0pt}%
        \@whiledim\dimen0<\dimexpr\textheight+1sp\relax\do{%
        \put(0,-\dimen0){\line(1,0){\textwidth}}%
        \addtolength{\dimen0 }{\unitlength}%
      }%
   \end{picture}%
  }%
 }%
}
\makeatother
 \makeatletter
 \setlength{\topskip}{13bp}
 \renewcommand\normalsize{%
  % \baselineskip to 13bp for \normalsize
  \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xipt{13bp}%
  % the following values are taken from size11.clo.
  \abovedisplayskip 11\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus6\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6.5\p@ \@plus3.5\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI 
   }
   \usepackage{parskip}
   \setlength{\parskip}{13bp}
   \makeatother
  \begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
  \par\kern-\prevdepth%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \nointerlineskip
  \vbox to 2\baselineskip{ }
   \lipsum[1]
   \end{document}
```

Comment: marvellous, but why there are 3\baselineskip instead of 2?

Comment: @pml The parskip, of course. Are you really sure you want big white stripes between paragraphs?

Comment: @pml A tip: if you want to "see" the empty `\vbox` write `\vbox to 2\baselineskip{\leaders\vrule width 1pt\vfill}`