# How to place an image at the right top of a document?

Tags: positioning

I've been learning LaTeX and this community has been very helpful. Currently, I'm trying to set up corporate letters but as a newbie I'm encountering a [variety](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43983/creating-letters-with-zero-margin-colored-headers-in-addition-to-the-regular-le) of [challenges](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44065/is-there-no-easier-way-to-float-objects-and-set-margins), so I'm posting them one by one instead of putting it in the comments... maybe this helps others as well.

Anyway, I am trying to implement this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44072/11045) that indicates that I can use `vbox` to float an image to the right of my header. I almost have this working, but I now try to adjust this to get my logo to stick to the top of the page. So I want to have this at the **right top** of my document. This is quite difficult! When I place the `vbox`, it creates unwanted spacing, for some odd reason. So I can not get the logo to be at the right top, even though I 'reset' every possible margin to 0 (in my opinion). Here is my distilled code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./img/}}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{DD4616}
\definecolor{white}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[margin=0cm, paperwidth=215.9mm, paperheight=30mm,top=0cm]{geometry}
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}
\fboxsep0pt

\pagecolor{orange}


\fbox{\vbox to 0pt{\hfill\fbox{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{logo}}}}

\end{document}
```

I've used a full black logo for illustrative purposes. Here you can see this:

[image]

The black line is the `vbox` border. For some reason, it jumps down. The only way to get rid of this that I found out about is this:

[Make an invisible vbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22355/make-an-invisible-vbox)

Which means that I need to add:

```
\edef\theprevdepth{\the\prevdepth}\nointerlineskip
\vbox to 0pt{...}\prevdepth=\theprevdepth
```

But there are two problems with this:

- I get an error with I try this (Improper `\prevdepth`.)
- More importantly, I really want to understand my code at this point, and get to master the basics of positioning elements. This feels overcomplicated and I do not understand it at all.

Is there any easy way to position an image at the right top of a document?

Comment: The latest [TUGboat](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Contents/contents32-3.html) has an article about designing letters with the [hletter package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hletter). If you haven't had a chance to look at it then it may be worth your while because it may save you some work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `\vbox` is anchored to the baseline. Also, since there is an additional `\topskip` at the top of the page between the header and the first line of text. So, jumping vertically `-\baselineskip-\topskip` pushes the `\vbox` of height `0pt` tight against the upper part of the page boundary.

Here's your MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{DD4616}
\definecolor{white}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\usepackage{fullpage}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fullpage
\usepackage[margin=0cm, paperwidth=215.9mm, paperheight=30mm]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{orange}%
\vspace*{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\topskip\relax}

\fbox{\vbox to 0pt{\hfill\fbox{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{html5}}}}
\end{document}
```

Some comments about the code:

- You have to use `\vspace*` for vertical space at the top of the page;
- `\dimexpr`...`\relax` is used as a dimension expression for combining lengths (or dimensions). You can also include the [`calc` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc) which allows you to forego this notation and use `-\baselineskip-\topskip` as is;
- I use `\setlength` rather than `\<len>=<dim>` - that's just the LaTeX way; the latter is the TeX way;
- `margin=0cm` is equivalent to `left=0cm,right=0cm,bottom=0cm,top=0cm` in [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry), so I dropped `top=0cm`;
- I set `\fboxsep` to `-\fboxrule`. This way the rule is actually drawn *within* the bounding box. Otherwise it would add `.4pt` to each of the sides (a total of `.8pt` vertically and horizontally) even if you use `\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}`;
- Loading [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) is sufficient, so you don't need to load [`color`](http://ctan.org/pkg/color).

Answer (score 12):

With TikZ and the `current page` node, you can place the image right at the top right corner of the page, just set the image node anchor to north east. All you need to add to your code is

```
\usepackage{tikz}
```

in the preamble, and then in your code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node [anchor=north east, inner sep=0pt]  at (current page.north east)
     {\includegraphics[height=3cm]{logo}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: logo at top right]

Answer (score 5):

It is normally sufficient to say:

```
\usepackage[margin=0cm, 
            paperwidth=215.9mm, 
            paperheight=30mm,
            top=-10pt]{geometry}
```

Geometry dimensions can be negative as well. In the above `top` is set to `top=-10pt`.

Comment: ...since `\topskip` is `10pt`.

Answer (score 4):

Without using a special geometry setting:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{orange}
\vspace*{\dimexpr-1in-\topmargin-\headsep-\headheight-\baselineskip}%
\hspace*{\dimexpr-1in-\evensidemargin-\parindent}%
\makebox[\paperwidth][r]{\frame{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{tiger}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution :)

Comment: It's indeed a very simple solution. Can I change the location of the image so to have some margins?

Comment: play with the `1in` value