# How can I fix a logo in the head-right of a page

Tags: header-footer, positioning

I am writing a scientific report for my internship, and I would like
to know if there is any easy command to put a logo in the page headers , for 
example in my case I would like it in the head-right.

PS: I am searching also to put two `minipages` in the same line and control their
position (space them each other or approach them like in CV's header with names , email address and photos).

Comment: I found a response in a duplicate question, thanks a lot :)

Comment: I didn't saw your comment because you did not ping me with `@`followed by the username. You can edit your question, add your code, mark it at click on symbol `{}` above the editing field. If you found an duplicate please name it here so that we can close this question.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44169/how-to-place-an-image-at-the-right-top-of-a-document?rq=1