# Create an exam paper with a logo

Tags: exam, paper

I would like to recreate something like this

[image: logo]

How would a header like that be achieved, would it be with the \maketitle command?

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%==============================================================
\begin{document}
%%
%% \thispagestyle{empty}
%
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[l]{0.1\textwidth}%
\noindent
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{logoUnimal.jpg}
\end{minipage}%
%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[l]{0.9\textwidth}%
\begin{center}
 {\normalsize \bfseries PANITIA UJIAN AKHIR SEMESTER JURUSAN TEKNIK MESIN UNIMAL \par
 \normalsize SEMESTER GANJIL 2015-2016\\[2pt]
  \par}
  \vspace{0.5cm}


\centering
\begin{tabular}{lllllll}
\textbf{Mata Kuliah}   & \textbf{:} & \textbf{Sitem Kendali}  &           & \textbf{Sifat}  & \textbf{:} & \textbf{Tutup Buku} \\
\textbf{Dosen Penguji} & \textbf{:} & \textbf{Fauzan, ST, MT} & \textbf{} & \textbf{Durasi} & \textbf{:} & \textbf{60 menit}  
\end{tabular}


\end{center}
\end{minipage}%
\par

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102066/how-to-insert-logo-in-exam-document-class?rq=1 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158643/make-an-exam-format-with-a-logo?rq=1.