# How to align an image right next to text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, wrapfigure, wrap

So I'm fairly new to latex and am mainly using the Overleaf site for writing my report. Now I have a particular page with info regarding my school etc. but I want the school logo sitting neatly in the right corner.

This is the code I'm using right now:

```
\begin{center}

{\LARGE Stagewerkplan over het onderzoek naar}\\[0.1cm]
\LARGE{\textit{"Ricochetbeschadiging op beton"}}

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{figure}[h!]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[scale=1.4]{Politie_Logo.pdf}
\end{figure}

\end{center}

\vspace{50mm}

\begin{flushleft}
\textbf{Student:}\\ \textit{Emiel Janssen}\\
\textbf{Studentnummer:}\\ \textit{349226}

\textbf{Stagecoördinator:}\\ \textit{Joost Hansté;\\
Senior Wetenschappelijk Forensisch Onderzoeker}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{5.5cm}
 \includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{Saxion_logo.pdf}
\end{wrapfigure} 


\textbf{Organisatie}\\ \textit{Politie Oost-Nederland\\
Afdeling Forensische Opsporing\\
Hermandad 2\\
7511 JN Enschede}

\textbf{Stagebegeleider:}\\ \textit{Drs. Maria Berk}


\end{flushleft}
```

As you can see, I tried to use the wrapit function, without succes.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. - aybe helpful [How to place an image at the right top of a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44169/124842)

Answer (score 4):

The `wrapfigure` has problems with `flushleft`  or `flushright`, more generally with lists environments. I suggest using   `\InsBoxR` from the `insbox` plain TeX macro package. It takes two mandatory arguments: the number of lines which remain untouched before the insertion, and the inserted box, and an optional argument: the number of supplementary shorter lines, in case the compiler doen't make a correct calculation.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\input{insbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

{\LARGE Stagewerkplan over het onderzoek naar}\\[0.1cm]
\LARGE{\textit{"Ricochetbeschadiging op beton"}}

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{figure}[h!]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[scale=1.4]{Politie_Logo.pdf}
\end{figure}
\end{center}

\vspace{50mm}

\begin{flushleft}
\textbf{Student:}\\ \textit{Emiel Janssen}\\
\textbf{Studentnummer:}\\ \textit{349226}

\textbf{Stagecoördinator:}\\ \textit{Joost Hansté;\\
Senior Wetenschappelijk Forensisch Onderzoeker}

\InsertBoxR{0}{\includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{Saxion_logo.pdf}}

\textbf{Organisatie}\\ \textit{Politie Oost-Nederland\\
Afdeling Forensische Opsporing\\
Hermandad 2\\
7511 JN Enschede}

\textbf{Stagebegeleider:}\\ \textit{Drs. Maria Berk}
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In this situation I would suggest the use of *tcolorbox* environment from the package of the same name. In my opinion, this would be much more efficent as it very customizable.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,draft]{article}

  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{tcolorbox}


  \begin{document}



% options for every upcomming tcolorbox environment
\tcbset{sidebyside,
  size=minimal,
  width=\textwidth,
  colback=white,
  lower separated=false, % no visible separation
  halign lower=flush right, % right side
  frame empty, % no borders
}


\begin{tcolorbox}[ halign upper=flush center] % upper = left side
  {\LARGE Stagewerkplan over het onderzoek naar}\\[0.1cm]
\LARGE{\textit{"Ricochetbeschadiging op beton"}}
\tcblower  %left right separation
  \includegraphics[scale=1.4]{Politie_Logo.pdf}
\end{tcolorbox}




\vspace{50mm}

\begin{tcolorbox}
  \textbf{Student:}\\ \textit{Emiel Janssen}\\
\textbf{Studentnummer:}\\ \textit{349226}

\textbf{Stagecoördinator:}\\ \textit{Joost Hansté;\\
Senior Wetenschappelijk Forensisch Onderzoeker}

\textbf{Organisatie}\\ \textit{Politie Oost-Nederland\\
Afdeling Forensische Opsporing\\
Hermandad 2\\
7511 JN Enschede}

\textbf{Stagebegeleider:}\\ \textit{Drs. Maria Berk}

\tcblower % left right separation

\includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{Saxion_logo.pdf}

\end{tcolorbox}




\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's no compelling reason that an image is included in a `figure` (or similar) environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\LARGE\centering
Stagewerkplan over het onderzoek naar\\
\textit{"Ricochetbeschadiging op beton"}
\end{minipage}% <-- don't forget
\makebox[0pt][r]{\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{example-image}}}

\end{center}

\vspace{50mm}

\begin{flushleft}
\makebox[\textwidth][r]{\raisebox{-\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=5.5cm,height=6cm]{example-image}}}

\textbf{Student:}\\ \textit{Emiel Janssen}\\
\textbf{Studentnummer:}\\ \textit{349226}

\textbf{Stagecoördinator:}\\ \textit{Joost Hansté;\\
Senior Wetenschappelijk Forensisch Onderzoeker}

\textbf{Organisatie}\\ \textit{Politie Oost-Nederland\\
Afdeling Forensische Opsporing\\
Hermandad 2\\
7511 JN Enschede}

\textbf{Stagebegeleider:}\\ \textit{Drs. Maria Berk}


\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

I used both `height` and `width` in order to get pictures which might be similar to the ones you have. The `showframe` package has only been loaded for showing the text block boundaries.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses standard LaTeX/TeX commands.

How this works, whether using wrapfig or any other package, is that you are overlaying the image on the page, then preventing the text from overlapping this image.  `\rlap` overlaps horizontally and `\raisebox` can be used to overlap vertically.  `\strut` is used here mostly because it is easier to type than `\leavevmode`.

In this case, the text doesn't overlap the image without modification.  However, by setting and resetting `\rightskip` you can protect the right size of the page from longer lines (at least inside flushleft).  The limitation is that you can only do this between paragraphs.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

{\LARGE Stagewerkplan over het onderzoek naar}\\[0.1cm]
\LARGE{\textit{``Ricochetbeschadiging op beton''}}

\vspace{2cm}

\includegraphics[scale=1.4]{Politie_Logo.pdf}

\end{center}

\vspace{50mm}

\begin{flushleft}
\textbf{Student:}\\ \textit{Emiel Janssen}\\
\textbf{Studentnummer:}\\ \textit{349226}

\textbf{Stagecoördinator:}\\ \textit{Joost Hansté;\\
Senior Wetenschappelijk Forensisch Onderzoeker}

\rightskip=\dimexpr 5.5cm+\columnsep\relax% not needed in this case
\strut\rlap{\makebox[\textwidth][r]{\raisebox{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox-\height}[0pt][0pt]
  {\includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{Saxion_logo.pdf}}}}%
\textbf{Organisatie}\\ \textit{Politie Oost-Nederland\\
Afdeling Forensische Opsporing\\
Hermandad 2\\
7511 JN Enschede}
\rightskip=0pt

\textbf{Stagebegeleider:}\\ \textit{Drs. Maria Berk}

\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

---

It occurred to me that you might be trying to bottom align the text and image.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

{\LARGE Stagewerkplan over het onderzoek naar}\\[0.1cm]
\LARGE{\textit{``Ricochetbeschadiging op beton''}}

\vspace{2cm}

\includegraphics[scale=1.4]{Politie_Logo.pdf}

\end{center}
\vfill

\hangindent=\bibindent
\textbf{Student:}\\ \textit{Emiel Janssen}

\hangindent=\bibindent
\textbf{Studentnummer:}\\ \textit{349226}

\hangindent=\bibindent
\textbf{Stagecoördinator:}\\ \textit{Joost Hansté;\\
Senior Wetenschappelijk Forensisch Onderzoeker}

\setlength{\rightskip}{\dimexpr 5.5cm+\columnsep}% not needed in this case
\hangindent=\bibindent
\textbf{Organisatie}\\ \textit{Politie Oost-Nederland\\
Afdeling Forensische Opsporing\\
Hermandad 2\\
7511 JN Enschede}

\hangindent=\bibindent
\textbf{Stagebegeleider:}\\
\strut\rlap{\makebox[\dimexpr \textwidth-\bibindent][r]{\smash{\includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{Saxion_logo.pdf}}}}%
\textit{Drs. Maria Berk}
\setlength{\rightskip}{0pt}%
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]